# How to localize "30 minutes" or "13h5m" strings coming from server?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string represented as "30 minutes" or "13h5m". I want to localize it and show user in their preference device language settings.

I know I have to use DateFormatter() and set dateFormat for above string  just like I was able to do for "13:55 AM"

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale!
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString )
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let date24 = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
```

How to set dateFormat for "30 minutes" or "13h5m" and localize it. Do I have to use NSDateComponentsFormatter().

Comment: I'm not clear on what your want. Can you give an example of the input string and your expected output string?

Comment: My input is "30 minutes" or "13h5m". I have to represent this time as japanese language like 30分. Input is coming as string.